# dark mode toggle in material ui

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am trying to implement a dark toggle in my website. I have gotten the toggle to show up in the correct place. I am using the `usestate` hook to implement the toggle functionality. However, on clicking the toggle, does not change the theme. I don't understand what is going wrong over here.

[image]

Here is the code of the different components.

I have implemented a component for the toggle theme button. Here is the code for `togglethemebutton.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
import { Switch } from '@mui/material';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

export default function ToggleThemeButton() {
  const [darkState, setDarkState] = useState(false);
  const palletType = darkState ? "dark" : "light";
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      type: palletType,
    }
  });
  const handleThemeChange = () => {
    setDarkState(!darkState);
  };

  return (
      <Switch checked={darkState} onChange={handleThemeChange} />
  );
}
```

I am using this component in the `Navbar.js` component.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
// material
import { alpha, styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Box, Stack, AppBar, Toolbar, IconButton } from '@mui/material';
// components
import Iconify from '../../components/Iconify';
//
import Searchbar from './Searchbar';
import AccountPopover from './AccountPopover';
import LanguagePopover from './LanguagePopover';
import NotificationsPopover from './NotificationsPopover';
import ToggleThemeButton from './ToggleThemeButton';
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

const DRAWER_WIDTH = 280;
const APPBAR_MOBILE = 64;
const APPBAR_DESKTOP = 92;

const RootStyle = styled(AppBar)(({ theme }) => ({
  boxShadow: 'none',
  backdropFilter: 'blur(6px)',
  WebkitBackdropFilter: 'blur(6px)', // Fix on Mobile
  backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.background.default, 0.72),
  [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
    width: `calc(100% - ${DRAWER_WIDTH + 1}px)`
  }
}));

const ToolbarStyle = styled(Toolbar)(({ theme }) => ({
  minHeight: APPBAR_MOBILE,
  [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
    minHeight: APPBAR_DESKTOP,
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 5)
  }
}));

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

DashboardNavbar.propTypes = {
  onOpenSidebar: PropTypes.func
};

export default function DashboardNavbar({ onOpenSidebar }) {
  return (
    <RootStyle>
      <ToolbarStyle>
        <IconButton
          onClick={onOpenSidebar}
          sx={{ mr: 1, color: 'text.primary', display: { lg: 'none' } }}
        >
          <Iconify icon="eva:menu-2-fill" />
        </IconButton>

        <Searchbar />
        <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />

        <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" spacing={{ xs: 0.5, sm: 1.5 }}>

          // here is the toggle button

          <ToggleThemeButton/>
          <LanguagePopover />
          <NotificationsPopover />
          <AccountPopover />
        </Stack>
      </ToolbarStyle>
    </RootStyle>
  );
}
```

Comment: I didn't test but It seems like the ToggleThemeButton should be working as expected for changing the darkState and darkTheme values but its missing to let know the proper component that these values have  changed so that the theme is updated

Comment: I'm quite new to React. I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you explain it a little more?

Comment: i'm new to material-ui so i'm not sure how theme should be used and update but what i mean is that your ToggleThemeButton should not only change the darkState and darkTheme but also the component that changes the theme which I think is the RootStyle  component

Answer (score 0):

A posible solution may be to move the logic to change the theme from the ToggleThemButton component to the NavBar and just pass the values needed like this:

ToggleThemeButton:

```
export default function ToggleThemeButton({handleThemeChange, darkState}) {
 
  return (
      <Switch checked={darkState} onChange={handleThemeChange} />
  );
}
```

Then in the NavBar component you could add a theme variable that its updated by the ToggleThemeButton, here i used a new createTheme with the pallete that has a background property just for testing (i don't know much about material ui)

Navbar:

```
export default function DashboardNavbar({ onOpenSidebar }) {

  const [darkState, setDarkState] = useState(false);     
  const palletType = darkState ? "dark" : "light";
  const darkTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
      type: palletType,
      background: {
        default: "#fff"
      }
    }
  });

  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(darkTheme);    

  const handleThemeChange = () => {
    setDarkState(!darkState);
  
    setTheme(createTheme({
      palette: {
        type: palletType,
        background: {
          default: !darkState? "#000" : "#fff"
        }
      }
    }))
  };

  return (
    <RootStyle theme={theme}>
      
         ..... <ToggleThemeButton  handleThemeChange={handleThemeChange} darkState={darkState} />  .... 
            
      </ToolbarStyle>
    </RootStyle>
  );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work! I tried this solution